# Rounding number in SSRS2008-R2 Reports

Tags: rounding, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report in RS.
One of the cells in my tablix have the following expression:

```
=Round((Fields!Volume.Value * 100) / First(Fields!Volume.Value,"RankingProduct"),2)
```

As you cann see, Im doing a Rule of three so the total is my first row of the `Volume` field.

Now, all the elements must sum 100%, but it does only if I take the `Round` function out.

The customer wants to see 2 decimals but at the same time wants all the elements to sum 100%. I understand both are mutually exclusive.

Example:
Value with all decimals: **0,005100972740331660000000000000**

Value with the 1st two decimals rounded: **0,010000000000000000000000000000**

So if you have one or two thousand of these will never reach 100% as I lose the precision.

So the only solution would be to leave all the decimals?

Comment: You can operate the calul only in the expression(without rounding), and then display the result with 2 decimal by changing the format of the cell.

Comment: What? I dont get what you are telling me. calul? You mean leave all the decimals and then just format the cell in excel?

Comment: Calcul*  , so you calcul your value with all the decimals. then you right click on the text box -> text box property -> number

Comment: Yes Kobi, thank you! mark your answe so I can upvote you. It was really easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate the simple calcul without rounding in the expression

```
=Round((Fields!Volume.Value * 100) / First(Fields!Volume.Value,"RankingProduct"),2)
```

become

```
=(Fields!Volume.Value * 100) / First(Fields!Volume.Value,"RankingProduct")
```

Then, you right click on the text box, choose Text box property -> Number, and you can select the 2 decimal display.

[image]